# Difference in cost using volume to print out to the screen

Tags: java, if-statement

I am in the first year of a computer programming program at a college and am stuck on this part of an assignment (The teacher is also all over the place and is hard to get clarification out of). This program we are making is for a shipping company to determine which package is the least expensive. We take in 3 variables (LxWxH) with two packages and calculate the volume and cost. But then we are supposed to have the statements on which one is better using volume? Here is the question

**The program must calculate the cost difference using the difference in volume, and give the following (in order of priority):

- If there is no difference, display the costs are the same
- If the cost of one is less than twice the other, display that it is “slightly more than”
- If the cost of one is less than three times the other, display that it is “twice”
- If the cost of one is less than four times the other, display that it is “triple”
- If the cost of one is less than five times the other, display that it is “quadruple”
  otherwise, display that it is the calculated multiple **

I have tried some if statements using the volumes and comparing them, then tired with the cost and comparing the two packages with the cost, but did not get the result.

```
    if (package1.calcVolume()==package2.calcVolume()){
        System.out.println("The cost of both packages are the same.");
    }
    else if (Math.max(package1.calcVolume(), package2.calcVolume()) == package1.calcVolume()){

        if (package1.calcVolume()<=(2*package2.calcVolume())){

            System.out.println("The cost of package 1 is slightly more.");
        }
        else if (package1.calcVolume()<=(3*package2.calcVolume())){

            System.out.println("The cost of package 1 is two times more.");
        }
        else if (package1.calcVolume()<=(4*package2.calcVolume())){

            System.out.println("The cost of package 1 is three times more.");
        }
    }
    else if (Math.max(package1.calcVolume(), package2.calcVolume())== package2.calcVolume()) {

        System.out.println("Package 2 is more.");   //Place holder for now
    }
```

When input 2,2,2 as LxWxH for package 1, and 1,1,1 for package 2 we are supposed to get 'The first package is triple more'.

Instead of I have gotten 'twice' and 'quadruple', and with this code I don't think I received anything.

Comment: using  your example, first box volume is 2x2x2= 8 and second box = 1x1x1 = 1. Your if case only check if first box is less than 4x second box volume which isnt the case, it is more. You are probably just missing a else case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you do something like `package1.calcVolume()` or `package2.calcVolume()` you are in essence calling the **calcVolume()** method within the **Package** class. It may not seem like it but this is time consuming not to mention unnecessary processing over and over again. Do it once:

```
double p1 = package1.calcVolume();
double p2 = package2.calcVolume();
```

Yes, it should be a double (or float) data type so as to properly get the **slightly less** portion of cost, so if it isn't already, correct the return type of the **calcVolume()** method. Now use **p1** or **p2** instead of always calling the **calcVolume()** method.

By removing all the calls you will ultimately remove a lot of code clutter which will make your code easier to read and follow but most importantly, your CPU will love you for it and so will the JVM. Well maybe not that much but at least you won't have to type so much.

Which package is 'less than' and which is 'greater than'? Is Package 1 twice as much Package 2 or is it Package 2 that is greater than Package 1? This can make for a lot of IF/ELSE. One set of IF/Else should suffice so it's a good idea to place these name designations into string variables as well and allow the code to determine which hold what string before the message is displayed to console:

```
String pkgHigh = "Package 'A'";
String pkgLow  = "Package 'B'";
```

Now, which package is of the larger size (volume):

```
p1 = 34;
p2 = 79;
```

Since we're only dealing with two packages we're going to assume that the volume for p1 will always be equal to or greater than the volume for p2 but hey, let's check but before we do that let's establish our Volume Difference Multiplier:

```
double volDiff = p1 / p2;
```

Here the **volDiff** double type variable is declared and initialized to a division of p1 and p2 (p1 / p2). This division works well if Package 'A' volume is *greater than* or *equal to* Package 'B'. Now let's see which package is actually larger in volume:

```
if (p1 != p2 && Math.max(p1, p2) == p2) {
    // Package 2 has the greater volume...
    volDiff = p2 / p1;
    pkgHigh = "Package 'B'";
    pkgLow =  "Package 'A'";
}
```

We could clearly see that p2 is larger than p1 because of the values we hard coded there. Hard coding won't be the case however when the code is run in the real world. These values will be determined upon entry of the actual package sizes. In any case we know in this case that p2 is larger than p1 and here is how the above IF block determines that:

- If **p1** does not equal **p2** AND The
  [Math.max()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/math_max_int.htm)
  method determines that **p2** is the larger of the two packages then:
- **p2** is greater than **p1** so divide **p2** by **p1** (p2 ÷ p1) to get the volume difference multiplier;
- Next, set the string variables **pkgHigh** to **"Package 'B'"** and
  **pkgLow** to **"Package 'A'"**. Now the message will display the proper package order which reflects to the higher and lower volume packages.

Now it's just a matter coding a series of IF/Else conditions so as to display the requested result. Here is what the entire code would look like:

```
// Double data types should be used for volume values.
double p1 = (double) 32;         // Volume of Package 1.
double p2 = (double) 32;         // Volume of Package 2.

String msg = "";                 // For Message String to Display.
String pkgHigh = "Package 'A'";  // Package designation variable.
String pkgLow =  "Package 'B'";  // Package designation variable.

// Double data type should be used for the Volume difference Multiplier.
double volDiff = p1 / p2;     // Volume Difference Multiplier.

/* Determine if the variables contents need to change.
   The IF block below checks to see if package 1 and
   package 2 are not equal and sees if the volume for
   package 2 is higher than package one. If both of these 
   pose as true then the Volume Difference Multiplier is
   calculated based on Package 2 divided by Package 1 
   since Package 2 is deemed to contain a higher volume.
   The package designation string variables are also changed
   to properly reflect which package is higher or lower 
   within the message strings. Otherwise package designators
   remain the very same as they were initialized to.    */
if (p1 != p2 && Math.max(p1, p2) == p2) {
    // Package 2 has the greater volume...
    volDiff = p2 / p1;
    pkgHigh = "Package 'B'";
    pkgLow =  "Package 'A'";
}

/* Determine the appropriate message to display in console based on the 
   Volume Difference Multitplier value. Package designation within the 
   messages has been determined pkg1/pkg2 initialization and within the 
   above IF block. */

// Packages are the same cost.
if (volDiff == 1.0d) {
    msg = "The shipping cost for " + pkgHigh + " and " + 
          pkgLow + " are the same.";
}
// One Package cost is slightly higher than the other.
else if (volDiff > 1.0d && volDiff < 2.0d) {
    msg = "The shipping cost for " + pkgHigh +
          " is slightly higher than it is for " + 
          pkgLow + ".";
}
// One Package cost is Twice as much as the other.
else if (volDiff >= 2.0d && volDiff < 3.0d) {
    msg = "The shipping cost for " + pkgHigh + 
          " is twice the cost than it is for " + 
          pkgLow + ".";
}
// One Package cost is Triple that of the other.
else if (volDiff >= 3.0d && volDiff < 4.0d) {
    msg = "The shipping cost for " + pkgHigh + 
          " is triple the cost than it is for " +
          pkgLow + ".";
}
// One Package cost is Quadruple that of the other.
else if (volDiff >= 4.0d && volDiff < 5.0d) {
    msg = "The shipping cost for " + pkgHigh + 
          " is quadruple the cost than it is for " + 
          pkgLow + ".";
}
// One Package cost is 'n' times greater than the other.
else {
    /* Round DOWN the Multiplier value by using 
    Math.round() and converting to integer.  */
    int multiple = Math.round((int) volDiff);
    msg = "The shipping cost for " + pkgHigh + " is " + 
          multiple + " times higher than it is for " + 
          pkgLow + ".";
}
System.out.println(msg); // Display the info message to Console.
```

Talk about code clutter. Yes, excessive commenting is clutter as well but all placed in the code to assist. It can be easily removed if so desired.